# Not able to search data for object from search box

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

I have issue related to the salesforce search box, I am not able to search the object related data by using this functionality. The Object is checked as searchable and field is also not lookup.

Useful Link : [Unable to Search a related record in Global Search](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165629/unable-to-search-a-related-record-in-global-search#new-answer)

From the above link and comments I understand that the Lookup and indexed fields can not be searched. But in my case the field is auto number and indexed.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, @Robert: Is this in Lightning Experience, Classic, or Community? Assuming this is Lightning Experience take a look into [Searchable Fields by Object in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_lex.htm&type=5).

Comment: Hi Jeferson, Thanks for your response. This issue is in classic.

Comment: Hey Robert, I would add more details to your question like: where are you trying to search, the object (custom or standard - if standard which one), and that this is in Classic.

Anyway, this information should be found on Help, see this [one for Custom Object in Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_custom_object.htm&type=5).

Comment: Hi, This is the custom object and not standard one

Comment: If I am adding the tab for this XYZ object in application then name data related to this object is searchable. But I don't want to add new tab for this object.

Comment: I see, reading the docs seems that the workaround is to have the tab and hide it through profiles.